# Basic Auth .htaccess on wp-login, but allow logout from woocommerce

Tags: htaccess, security, wp-login-form, authentication

I use a `.htaccess` basic auth on my WC site to help prevent hackers accessing `wp-login`, which works well... except with WooCommerce if a logged in customer wants to logout from their account - upon clicking the logout link - they are greeted by the Basic Auth popup asking them to "authorise" (generated by our `.htaccess`).

On Woocommerce dashboard:

> Hello MrTest (not MrTest ? Log out)  << clicking on "Log out" brings up the Basic Auth login box.... how can we avoid that ?

Here is the content of our htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
AuthName "Authorized"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/.pswrdfile
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

In WooCommerce settings, the Logout endpoint is: `customer-logout` and the logout link URL shows:

```
example.com/shop/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=2e343434
```

So how to change the `.htaccess` to allow `wp-login.php?action=logout` to pass through the basic auth?

I tried this but it fails to work;  I have Apache server with latest versions.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login.php$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=logout
 RewriteRule ^ - [E=noauth]

 <FilesMatch "^(wp-login.php)">

    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AuthName "Protected page. If you are not allowed to be here, leave the page"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/htaccess/myhtaccess"
    Require valid-user

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=noauth

    Satisfy any

 </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: What version of Apache are you on?

Comment: @MrWhite Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

From the answer in [Password protect a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url), we can reverse the condition. To quote his answer,

> You should be able to do this using the combination of `mod_env` and the
> `Satisfy any` directive. You can use `SetEnvIf` to check against the
> `Request_URI`, even if it's not a physical path. You can then check if
> the variable is set in an `Allow` statement. So either you need to log
> in with password, or the `Allow` lets you in without password:

```
# Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/shop/my-account/customer-logout/ require_auth=false

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```